# Unable to load a Datatable on click of a button

Tags: datatables

I am trying to load a datatable on click of a button outside the datatable.

below is my piece of code

```
  $('#buttonToLoadDatatable').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
                type:        "GET",
                url:"../fhParser/fhParser/downloadAndParseResume/v1",           
        }).done(function (result) {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-
             12 hidden-xs'l>r>"+
                    "t"+
                    "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": '<span class="input-group-addon"><i 
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>'
                },                      
                "bDestroy": true,
                "data":result,
                "iDisplayLength": 15,
              /**this portion was because I have a collapsible rows**/
                "columns": [ 
                            {
                                "class":          'details-control',
                                "orderable":      false,
                                "data":           null,
                                "defaultContent": ''
                            },
                            {  "data":"email"  }
                        ],
                rowCallback: function (row, data) {},
                filter: false,
                info: false,
                ordering: false,
                processing: true,
                retrieve: true,  

                "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                   runAllCharts()
                }
               // rowCallback: function (row, data) {}
            } );
             console.log( result );

            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            });
    });
```

When I print the value in the browser console, it comes correctly as 
{"email": "triedandtest@gmail.com"}, but it does not display in the datatable

There is no error also in the console or at the backend

Comment: Isnt it working even for the fist time?

Comment: Hi G_S, Thanks for the response.
No :(
I have changed my json to {"data": [{"email" :"triedandtest@gmail.com"}] }.
Still it does not display the data

Comment: and no errors too?

Comment: No ...It doesnot throw any errors..i printed the json in the console..it comes correctly

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: I used http://json.parser.online.fr/ to validate the json and its parsed correctly

Comment: Is it that you should send an array of objects?

Comment: I have changed my json to {"data": [{"email" :"triedandtest@gmail.com"}] which is an array..still no luck. I am just trying to fill one row ad one column..to see if it workss

Comment: do you have something related to runAllCharts() method?

Comment: It came with the theme I bought from bootstrap.
I commented it and tried but the result is same

Comment: We should have "data": dataresult.data , Isnt it?

Comment: You have that method in your code right?

Comment: Thanks for trying so much. Am not clear about your last comment
Yes I do have the method in my code

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Can do a console.log of result?

Comment: I am expecting statement  "data":result, in your data table configuratoin to be  "data":result.data , since your response is  {"data": [{"email" :"triedandtest@gmail.com"}]

Comment: It gives me this as mentioned in the last line of the problem statement
{"email": "triedandtest@gmail.com"}

Comment: {"email": "triedandtest@gmail.com"} or [{"email": "triedandtest@gmail.com"}] ? notice the array representation

Comment: yes I gave you the content. , I modified the json as i wrote earlier

"I have changed my json to {"data": [{"email" :"triedandtest@gmail.com"}]}"

Comment: can you check the answer and let me know if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you replace your code to

```
$('#buttonToLoadDatatable').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
                type:        "GET",
                url:"../fhParser/fhParser/downloadAndParseResume/v1",           
        }).done(function (result) {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-
             12 hidden-xs'l>r>"+
                    "t"+
                    "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": '<span class="input-group-addon"><i 
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>'
                },                      
                "bDestroy": true,
                "data":result.data,
                "iDisplayLength": 15,
              /**this portion was because I have a collapsible rows**/
                "columns": [ 
                            {
                                "class":          'details-control',
                                "orderable":      false,
                                "data":           null,
                                "defaultContent": ''
                            },
                            {  "data":"email"  }
                        ],
                rowCallback: function (row, data) {},
                filter: false,
                info: false,
                ordering: false,
                processing: true,
                retrieve: true,  

                "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                   runAllCharts()
                }
               // rowCallback: function (row, data) {}
            } );
             console.log( result );

            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            });
    });
```

and check if that works

FYI changed  `"data":result`, to  `"data":result.data`,

Comment: G_S thanks a lot. It works like a charm.
Although the JSON also I modified a bit to 
{data: Array(1)} when expanded have 
0:{email: "som.dwaipayan@gmail.com"} //Note: 0 implies the index
from
{"data": [{email :"triedandtest@gmail.com"}] which was mentioned in the problem statement

Comment: I am happy that it worked. If you are facing any other issue, do let me know. I can check on it